# Drupal 7. "User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: common."

Tags: drupal-7

When I've updated my Drupal website from 7.44 to 7.50 I now receive the following warning:

`User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: common. In order to fix this, put the module back in its original location. For more information, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1128 of /home/system/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).`

This is well known warning and described here https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

But the problem is that no method didn't helped:

- There is no reference to this module in `system` table in database;
- Modules like `Module Missing Message Fixer` do not see it;
- Drush doesn't see it either.

Database update, cleared cache after each update were done.

I also tryed to find references in `.info` and `.module` files in folders, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by updating database after upgrade of drupal version.
Please do /update.php it will update your database and It might solve your errors.

Comment: Yes, sure, and also cleared cache and even registry rebuild with drush.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try restoring the missing module to the file system?

Comment: There is no such module, I assume that it was a core module in some previous versions, but not existed in 7.44 and 7.50. I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: Refer to this link, if you know the module name, you can disable it using mysql query. https://www.drupal.org/node/157632. Also clear cache.

Comment: Nothing helps. There is no `name='common'` in `system` table, cleared `cache_bootstrap` completely, rebuild registry, cleread cache.